# Is there a way to automatically indent nested commands in TeX source code on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

Such as for enumerate environments to have indentation, in addition to tweaks to automatically indent entries in tables or matrices in math mode. For example, something like

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
        1.1
  \item 2
\end{enumerate}
\begin{align*}
F(-x) & =-(-x)^2 & G(-x) & =-(-x)^4 & H(-x) & =-(-x)^6 \\ 
      & =-x^2    &       & =-x^4    &       & =-x^6    \\    
      & =F(x)    &       & =G(x)    &       & =H(x)    
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Most likely not. You can consider using [`latexindent`](//ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) *outside* of the online editor.

Comment: @Werner, thanks! I just recently discovered latexindent, and thought it would be very useful to have a real-time script of a similar kind running in overleaf..

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.) Indeed there's no way to do this, I'm afraid. Sorry!

Comment: This would be a superbly useful feature to have in overleaf. Surprisingly, unlike many IDEs for regular programming languages, not many latex editors have proper indenting capabilities...

Comment: This is one of the main reasons I had to set up an offline setup.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way. [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), [imnotthere  : *support personnel at Overleaf*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226/imnothere), [Joris Kinable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32887/joris-kinable) have said so.

Added this answer to remove it from the unanswered queue

Comment: For reference, latexindent.pl is actively developed and maintained, and is available as part of texlive, Miktex and is on ctan. Project home page: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

Comment: latexindent.pl is a wonderful package. and the reason for me to shift to a local test distribution

Comment: That's really great to hear, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I am working in Overleaf also and needed this feature. Based on the top answer, I searched for a non-overleaf alternative. This online formatter worked like a gem for me: https://c.albert-thompson.com/latex-pretty/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).